# Can I replace libcurl with libevent for file download only

Tags: libcurl, libevent

I am new to libevent and experimenting some stuff here. I am given a URL of a file, I need to download this file using URL. can I perform this task using libevent in anyway ?

I am able to perform above task using libcurl. But interested to know if libevent can be used to download a file from server given URL ?

Comment: These libraries are for very different things. `libevent` is used to enable asynchrnous file handler notifications, but `libcurl` is an HTTP client library. What do you see in the documentation for `libevent` that makes you think it can also act as an HTTP client?

Comment: @Knetic
From http://libevent.org/ : 
"Libevent includes support for several useful protocols, including DNS, HTTP, and a minimal RPC framework."

I am able to establish connection with server from libevent, but I am not able to download files.
Also, I am able to see few examples of libevent client code around: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=libevent%20http%20client%20example